# MongoDb - Is $where more performant when using functions stored in db.system.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mongodb

MongoDb recommends that "In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another operator" due to perframce reasons. However, it appears that we can store Javascript functions server-side using the special table `system.js`.

So instead of doing this:

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return this.credits == this.debits; } } );
```

Do this instead:

```
db.system.js.save({ _id : 'queryFunction` , value : function() { return this.credits == this.debits; } });
...
db.myCollection.find( { $where: 'queryFunction' ); //not sure about syntax
```

Would the second variant reap any performance benefits; and if so, are they significant?

---

References:

- [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)
- [`db.system.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)

Comment: It's trivial to try and measure, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't help.

In either case the function will be loaded as string and compiled to a javascript function before it is executed by MongoDBs Javascript engine for every single document. Whether you load it via network or via a query to `system.js` won't make much of a difference, and even when it would, the bulk of the runtime would be the execution of the function in most cases.